# Text Editor in Flutter

Tags: json, string, flutter, text, dart

I am building a blog app and I want the users to create posts and I've found that there is a library for that purpose and it's zefyr.

I've created an editing screen and everything is going okay and I can edit and retrieve the written string.

but I got it retrieved without the editing I've done such that a bold text.

what is the cause of that?

My Retrieve Code:

```dart
data = notusDocument.toPlainText().toString();
```

it retrieves it without the editing I have done.

How to achieve that?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a TextController

```dart
TextController myTextController = TextController();
```

```dart
TextFormField(
   controller: myTextController,
   ...
)
```

Then to read the text

```dart
String data = myTextController.text;
```

Comment: it has a zefyr controller which has a value of type notus document which we retrieve data from, you can have a look at the library, anyway thank you